# Stopping rules for Markov Chains

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

The following is a quote from [Lifting Markov Chains to Speed up Mixing](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/stoc2.pdf), by Chen, Lovasz, and Pak:

> ...Thus we have described a (randomized) stopping rule that, for any starting node, stops in an expected number $O(\sqrt{n})$ steps, and the probability of stopping at each node is at least 1/2 its stationary probability. By standard results (see e.g. [9]), this implies that the mixing time is $O(\sqrt{n})$.

My question: I would like a precise reference for this fact, especially one which has a proof I can read. The reference [9] is [Mixing Times](http://www.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/mixtimes.ps) by Lovasz and Winkler, and I was unable to find this statement in there.

Moreover, there is some ambiguity of what a mixing time of means; what I want it to mean in this case is that except from the eigenvalue at $1$, every other eigenvalue of the chain has modulus at most $1-c/\sqrt{n}$ for some constant $c>0$.

Can someone provide a precise reference?

Answer (score 3):

The condition means that the *separation distance* is smaller than 1/2. The conclusion depends on the definition of the *mixing time*.  For example, if the mixing time is the expected time for the optimal strong uniform stopping rule (as e.g. in [my thesis](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/time57.pdf)), then this holds.  If the mixing time is the convergence in $\ell_\infty$ distance, then this is "almost true", up to a log factor.  The Lovasz-Winkler paper we mentioned proves several equivalent (and non-equivalent) definitions of mixing times which the reader might find useful.  For classical results on the separation distance, see [this paper](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/strong87.pdf) by Aldous and Diaconis.

Answer (score 0):

We know that (on page 12) the mixing time is $$\mathcal{H} = \max_{i} \ \max_{j}(H(i,j)-H(\pi,j))$$

It seems that $H(i,j) = O(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: PEV: I would appreciate if you could make precise the ways in which your post is relevant to the question asked.